# node.js forEach not blocking

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreach

I am trying to process data from a MySQL table by pulling 7 fields and creating another table with the table name matching field 1 and the other 6 fields are data put into the fields of newly created table.  Field 1 is an identifier for a device and I want to log any changes to the other information in the other 6 fields.  For Example...

Table A

Row 1 ---> 90:59:AF:4E:C3:30 | Mark | 10051 | PV320 | 192.168.1.199 | 1.35 | 026132956282

Row 2 ---> 90:59:AF:55:A3:BA | Buds | 10050 | PV200 | 192.168.1.123 | 1.37 | 026132966540

I want to create

Table 90:59:AF:4E:C3:30

Row 1 ---> Mark | 10051 | PV320 | 192.168.1.199 | 1.35 | 026132956282

and..Table 90:59:AF:55:A3:BA

Row 1 ---> Buds | 10050 | PV200 | 192.168.1.123 | 1.37 | 026132966540

The problem I am running into, is that I have about 70 records, and when I try to run my code, I cannot get it to wait for the first table to be created and populated before creating and populating the next table.  I know my syntax is correct, because it will create and populate several tables before throwing 'Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections'

Here is my code:

```
function read_all_devices(){
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : db_host, 
    user     : user, 
    password : pass, 
    database : my_db'
});
connection.query('SELECT macaddress, customer_name, ssh_port, validation_type, ip, version, serialnumber FROM ' + table + ' WHERE 1', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        log(RED+err);
    }
    if (!err && rows[0]) {
        rows.forEach(function(current){
            var schema = mysql.createConnection({
                host    : db_host,
                user    : user,
                password: pass,
                database: 'information_schema'
            }); 
            schema.query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = my_db AND table_name = '"+current.macaddress+"';", function(error, result) { //Check to see if the table already exists
                if (error){
                    log("ERROR: " + error);
                }
                else if (result[0]) { 
                    log("Table for " + current.macaddress + " already exists.");
                    update_historical_table(current.macaddress, current.customer_name, current.ssh_port, current.validation_type, current.ip, current.version, current.serialnumber);
                }
                else {
                    log("Table for " + current.macaddress + " did not exist....creating.");
                    create_table_by_mac(current.macaddress, current.customer_name, current.ssh_port, current.validation_type, current.ip, current.version, current.serialnumber, update_historical_table);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    connection.end();
});
```

}

```
function create_table_by_mac(mac_to_create, name, port, val_type, ip, version, sn, printer, callback) {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : db_host, 
    user     : user, 
    password : pass, 
    database : my_db
});
connection.query("CREATE TABLE `" + mac_to_create + "` (recnum INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, customer_name VARCHAR(30) default NULL, ssh_port VARCHAR(6) default NULL, serialnumber VARCHAR(20) default NULL, validation_type VARCHAR(20) default NULL, ip VARCHAR(20) default NULL, version VARCHAR(20) default NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (recnum));", function (create_error, create_result) {
    if (create_error) {
        log("ERROR Creating Table: "+ create_error);
    } else {
        log("Table " + mac_to_create + " created");
    }
});
callback(mac_to_create, name, port, val_type, ip, version, sn);

function update_historical_table(mac_to_update, name, port, val_type, ip, version, sn) {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : db_host, 
    user     : user, 
    password : pass, 
    database : my_db
});
connection.query("INSERT INTO `"+ mac_to_update + "` (`customer_name`, `ssh_port`, `validation_type`, `ip`, `version`, `serialnumber`, `printer_type`) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + port + "', '" + val_type + "', '" + ip + "', '" + version + "', '" + sn + "');", function(err, rows) {
    connection.end();
    if (!err) {
        log(GREEN+"Table "+ WHITE + mac_to_update + GREEN + " updated successfully.");
    } else if (err) {
        log(RED+"ERROR Updating "+ WHITE + mac_to_update + ".");
        log(RED+"ERROR MESSAGE: " + err);
    }
});
```

}

This is the best I could get the code to paste.  If there are any questions as to what I am trying to do here, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` executes synchronously, but it won't automatically block everything. If you do asynchronous work within that block, `forEach` is not smart enough to wait until the callback is finished. Take a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, particularly [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries). It'll look something like this:

```
var async = require('async');
async.eachSeries(rows, functionToHandleEachRow, functionToBeCalledAfterEverythingIsFinished);
```

You'll want to look at the API for further details on the iterator and callback implementations.

Comment: Excellent. I had to play with the callbacks a little (I am fairly new to node.js and I am not great with callbacks yet) but I got it working.  Thanks for the help.